# Xcode - Include a UIView above UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a TableViewController, that manages a UITableView. Now I want to make a header menu (different for the one in navigation bar by default) and a search bar (also different from the default one). The problem is that I try to drop a UIView above the TablewView, but I can't, it always goes inside the tableview (in the storyboard).

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use something else than `UITableViewController`.

Subclass `UIViewController` and add a tableview into it, but with a `y` position that is `>0`. Now, set your `UIViewController` subclass as the `delegate` and `dataSource` of that `UITableView` and implement all the necessary methods.  ( references [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) )

You will be able to change the layout of that `tableView` and add whatever view you want to add to the `self.view`

Comment: Thanks a lot Olotiar! I will have a lot of work until the end of the day reconstructing my controllers :).

Comment: You're welcome. If you are doing that more than once, consider creating a generic `UIViewController` and re-use it several times.

Comment: Hummm Is it possible to do something like. A generic UIView design on storyboard, and save it like a object to reuse? Like a view that is repeated on a list, like a photoview for thumbnails?

Another thing, should I use a costum navigationViewController to costumize my navigationBar, or should I do it inside the genericViewController? (I want that navigation bar to be in everyView, so it's like a template)

Comment: If you want to customize your NavigationBar, and if you target iOS 5 and more, use `UIAppearance`, like `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` (put that code in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{` of your `AppDelegate`. If you want more info on how to further customize (and how to do it for iOS 4-) I recommmend Googling or asking a separate question. And you sound like learning about categories might be a good idea

Comment: Yeah, I've read about categories. Like I'm coming on the first months in IOS dev, and I came from Front End, it's being a little hard to interiorize some concepts. But you gave me some good insights to study more. Tks a lot for your time!